# how do i fix a revert opt code

Tags: transactions

i was hoping someone could help, I sent some ether to an initial coin offering and got my  coins in return all good.
But when i tried to do it again i get Tx receipt status failed and when i look at the transaction on etherscan i get Value transfer did not complete most likely as a result of a revert opcode.
I am new to this industry so i don't no where to start.thanks smarx tx,
0xf534e41bf64722e1daa35c626815374a19fc4bdca1ba6113e3ec67e4de837182

Comment: If you can share the transaction hash, someone may be able to figure out what happened. (It typically involves reading the code from the contract.)

Comment: sorry like i said very new to this the Tx code is; 0x0f8a7385f6eac9121e36978e235acfe036e1fedbea4416a63a5bde992ae1d13e

Comment: Unfortunately, it looks like the source code for the contract isn't available (at least on etherscan.io). Without the source, it's hard to figure out went wrong. It's not *impossible*, but it would involve reading the raw bytecode, which is quite difficult.

Comment: You're probably better off asking for help from the people running the ICO.

Comment: Actually, I have a guess. https://www.carvertical.com/blog/the-reason-we-changed-the-soft-cap-and-hard-cap/ mentions a minimum purchase cap of 0.1 ETH. I think your failed transaction was sending less than that. Maybe that's the problem?

Comment: thanks very much i think your right doh should have read the instructions as my wife would say.